# Pick value without surrounding object with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

With

```
const _ = require('lodash');
_.pick({"page":3}, 'page');
```

I get `{ page: 3 }`. I just need the value `3` so I have to access `varname.page`.

Is there a way to pick from an array and directly return the value/object with lodash?

I just don't like the repetition in here:

```
let pageNumber = _.pick(params, 'page[number]');
            if (!_.isEmpty(pageNumber)) {
                pageNumber = parseInt(pageNumber['page[number]']);
            }
```

Comment: You don't need lodash or any library for that, it's a basic feature of JavaScript! See [@MadaraUchiha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38189254/1079573)

Comment: Oh, how could I miss that. Please vote for deletion/closing!

Comment: You can delete your own post, I think, by clicking the `delete` button underneath it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhhh.... I might be missing something obvious but....

```js
const myObj = {"page": 3}
console.log(myObj.page); // 3
//alternatively
console.log(myObj["page"]); // 3
```